# Display SQL items by Day

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display my whole table but grouped by days.

So after I

```
SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY event_date, event_time
```

i would like them to be displayed like this.

```
<table>
<th><?php echo date('W M D', strtotime($row->event_date)); ?></th>
<tr>
<td>Location Time Event</td>
</tr>

<th><?php echo date('W M D', strtotime($row->event_date)); ?></th>
<tr>
<td>Location Time Event</td>
<td>Location Time Event</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

But I cant find an example anywhere. Only grouping and suming items.

EDIT. I don't want to add the days but display the items by days.

Example output

```
September 8th
 -- Location Time Event
 -- Location Time Event

September 9th 
 -- Location Time Event

October 10th
 -- Location Time Event
```

EDIT 2.

Rewrote the code

```
<?php 
            require_once("config.php");
            $results = $db->get_results('SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY event_date, event_time');
            foreach($results as $row){
                $row->id // all the items are available as objects
            }
            $curr_date = '' 
            foreach($results as $row){
            if ($curr_date != $row->event_date){
            /* Handle the date’s title here */
            printf("<h1>%s</h1>", $row->event_date);
            $curr_date = $row->date
            }
            /* Handle row items here */
            printf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>", $row->presenter , $row->location); 
            }
          ?>
```

Still receiving error. The error appears around here $row->id with unexpected T_VARIABLE

Comment: You can iterate through them and add it to an array, if you want to do it in PHP.  make the index the date.  $events[$row->event_date][] = $row;  If they are the same date, they will get added together

Comment: Or don't make multiple loops. Just make an if clause in the loop and print out the date and the HTML needed to split the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work thanks for the help!

Code:

```
$results = $db->get_results('SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY event_date, event_time');
            $curr_date = ''; 
            foreach($results as $row){
            if ($curr_date != $row->event_date){
            /* Handle the date’s title here */
            printf("<h1>%s</h1>", $row->event_date);
            $curr_date = $row->event_date;
            }
            /* Handle row items here */
            printf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr></br>", $row->presenter , $row->location); 
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY event_date, event_time");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $event_date = $row['event_date'];
    $location_event = $row['some event'];
    if ($event_date == $last_date) {
        echo "<tr><td>$location_event</td></tr>";
    } else {
        echo "<th>$event_date</th>";
        echo "<tr><td>$location_event</td><tr>";
    }
    $lastdate = $event_date;
}
```

Comment: I receive UNDEFINED VARIABLE: LAST_DATE for `if ($event_date == $last_date) {`

Comment: initialize $last_date before you enter the While loop so that it has a value the first time through.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this, but it creates a multi-dimensional array that allows you to iterate through the dates and the subsequent times.

```
$tempArray = array();

$query = "SELECT event_date, event_time FROM events ORDER BY event_date, event_time";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    $event_date = $row[event_date];
    $event_time = $row[event_time];

    $tempArray[$event_date][] = $event_time;
}

foreach($tempArray as $k1=>$event_date) {
    echo "<h1>$event_date</h1>";

    foreach($tempArray[$event_date] as $k2=>$event_time) {
        echo "<p>$event_time</p>";
    }
}

mysqli_free_result($result);

unset($tempArray);
```